# ssh in java (run commands on another machine)

Tags: java, ssh

I was wondering whether there was a simple way to do this as part of a java program.

I would like to be able to ssh into another machine and perform commands on that machine.

A simple example would be:
    runtime.exec("say hello world");
would (on a mac) have a text-to-speech engine speak hello world.

Is there a way to have java run this method on another machine?

Also, assuming the above is possible, is there a way to  ssh into more than one machine at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: I think [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+ssh&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflbh) is working today.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of libraries to do this. I suggest [Ganymed SSH-2](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/), that is also mentioned in the [official OpenSSH website](http://www.openssh.org/java.html). In the same site, you can also find other libraries that you can use for Java.

This is an example of `ls -r` command executed via SSH, using Ganymed SSH-2:

```
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;

[...]

public static ArrayList<String> lsViaSSH(String hostname, String username, String password, String dir) {
    ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();

    try
    {
        Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);

        conn.connect();

        boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);

        if (isAuthenticated == false) {
            return null;
        }

        Session sess = conn.openSession();

        sess.execCommand("ls -r " + dir);

        InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

        while (true)
        {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            ls.add(line);
        }

        sess.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(ls.get(0)))
        return null;

    return ls;
}
```

This is not the only function needed in order to execute a command via SSH, but I hope it could be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

As far as executing at the exact same time?  Not really unless you intend to spawn multiple threads to deal with your list of remote machines.

Answer (score 1):

given that you're on a system where ssh command is available and [ssh keys are set up](http://paulkeck.com/ssh/) to avoid entering passwords the easiest would be just

```
runtime.exec("ssh remote_comp 'say hello world'");
```

Comment: Why do you need the single quotes?

Comment: because it's easier than double quotes that you'd have to escape (\")

Comment: Why do we need quotes at all? `man ssh` shows `ssh...[user@]hostname [command]` so I'd assume we could just write the command as we normally would. How can I determine when I need quotes in a scenario like this? You've been a big help :) thank you.

Comment: @Steve command has to be in quotes to make shell pass it to ssh as a single entity. To prevent shell from expanding parts of command on its own. `ssh somehost echo 1; ls` will run echo on remote and ls on local, `ssh somehost 'echo 1; ls'` will run both echo and ls on remote

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to take a look to the [Apache MINA SSHD](http://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/index.html), it can be used to write both a client and a server with java